# Authentication error when updating

Tags: software-center, kde

How can I resolve the error shown in the photo.

I have changed my desktop to gnome and managed to update but when I use this desktop my OS refuses to update.  When I update with Plasma KDE, this works.

[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1/q71/s720x720/1453259_211671775707708_1788552977_n.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Can you install it using `sudo apt-get install wireshark`?

Comment: @Downvoters: why? If its a duplicate, close it, what is the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure how do you do it using the software-center, but you can install it from the command line using:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

and then it may ask you whether to install unauthenticated packages, don't worry, this warning usually means they are not from the main Ubuntu repositories, but *in most cases* reliable to install, press `y`.